# change kendo grid row color conditionally using Angular ngClass or ngStyle does not work

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

Im using a Kendo detailed view Grid,in one my detail view data there is row which i want to be highlighted if the value meets my condition,i tried the following but i cant achieve it
here is my main grid component,

```
  <div *kendoGridDetailTemplate="let dataSource">
  <app-category-details>
  </app-category-details>
   </div>
```

app-category-detail is the detail component which is :

```
 template: `
      <kendo-grid
      [data]="dataSource"      
      scrollable="none"
      [navigable]="true"
      kendoGridFocusable>
     <kendo-grid-column field="deviceIP" title="Device IP">
     </kendo-grid-column>
     <kendo-grid-column field="comments" title="Comments"  [ngClass]="dataSource==='VPN Gateway' ? 'positive':'positive'" >
     </kendo-grid-column>
     </kendo-grid>
```

my condition is dataSource==='VPN Gateway' but this code does not give any error and does not change anything also, seems i can't use dataSource directly there,and if i use dataSource.comments it gives me the error that cant get the comments value of unknown.positive is a css class to change back ground.

Comment: I dont know Kendo-ui exactly but i think that  if datasource is undefined, kendo grid just doesnt display the data. This will prevent an extra ngif  call on this component for example: if you hold an Observable which value later (delayed) exists. KendoGrid render its self after the data exists.  If you want to work with comments from datasource check at first *ngIf="datasource" after this comments will be correctly validated

Comment: @Cobi can you write here what you mean please?thanks

Comment: why would your data source be a string? What do you expect the grid to do with that?

Comment: @MikeS. dataSource is a json data consist of diffrent fields(comments,....),but when i want to say if dataSource.comments==='something' ,it gives me an error which cant find the comments of an unknown dataSource

Comment: Use the `kendoGridCellTemplate` directive to access your field: https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/grid/columns/templates/#toc-cell-template

Comment: `<kendo-grid-column field="comments" title="Comments" *ngIf="dataSource"  [ngClass]="dataSource.comments ==='VPN Gateway' ? 'positive':'positive'" >
</kendo-grid-column>` try this